# very basic dojo: button not displaying icon

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

i am new to dojo and i am trying to make a button with an image, but the image does not show, besides, when one clicks the button, it correctly shows the "hi" alert.

the "zoom_in.png" image is right in the same directory with the html. And firebug shows no errors or warnings.

Update. thanks to ed, i managed to get it working via the declarative approach

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>    
    <script>require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button"]);</script>

    <style>
    .zoom_in_icon {
    background-image: url('zoom_in.png');
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoom_in_icon'" type="button">
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
        require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){
            alert( "Thank you! ");
        });
    </script>
</button>
<div id="result2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, programatically, the problem persists

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Button</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"  data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

<style>
.zoom_in_icon {
    background-image: url('zoom_in.png');
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>

<script>
require([
"dijit/form/Button",
"dojo/domReady!"
], 
function(Button) {    
    new Button({
    title: 'Zoom in', iconClass:'zoom_in_icon',
    onClick: function() { alert("hi"); }}, "zoom_in").startup();  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
     <button  id="zoom_in" type="button"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Try adding <img src="images/zoom_in.png" width = 30 height = 30> before <\div>

Comment: code has no divs, i suppose you mean </button>, didn't work either. thanks anyway

Comment: in the jsfiddle after <\button> there is a <\div>. I mean between them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the button programatically you need to call startup() on the new Button, and you don't need the data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" or the parse in the html, if you want to create it declaratively you don't need the new button, but you need to set the icon in the html.
See the Programatic example here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Button.html

Comment: Is the URL correct? Do you see zoom_in.png being loaded?  And which way do you want to go programmatic or declarative?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle for a programmatic one: http://jsfiddle.net/edchat/dox42qye/2/

Comment: i got it working declarative however, programatic still doesnt work.